# Read in feather file directly from GitHub in R

Tags: r, loaddata, feather, read-data

How can I read in a `.feather` file from the web (e.g. GitHub) in R? I can read formats as `.csv` or `.dta` from GitHub directly as `raw`

```
# CSV 
coursedata <- read.csv(file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MarcoKuehne/seminars_in_applied_economics/main/Data/GF_2020.csv')

# DTA 
library(haven)
soep <- read_dta("https://github.com/MarcoKuehne/seminars_in_applied_economics/blob/main/Data/soep_lebensz_en.dta?raw=true")
```

But the same approach fails for `arrow` and `read_feather`.

```
library(arrow)
digital <- read_feather("https://github.com/MarcoKuehne/seminars_in_applied_economics/blob/main/Data/Digital_Literacy_EN.feather?raw=true")
```

Is there a direct way or a nested command? Or am I required to download the file manually or programmatically as a temporary file?